# Rails ActiveRecord Arels: Unsupported argument type: String. Construct an Arel node instead

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, generate-series

I'm using `Arels` for creating query. In this query, I use `generate_series` function. Here is my code:

```
    def generate_series
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('GENERATE_SERIES', [start_date, end_day, '1 day'])
    end

def start_date
      Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(<<-SQL
         CASE WHEN DATE_PART('hour', NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'ICT') < #{Time.now - 3days} THEN (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '14 days') ELSE (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '13 days') END
      SQL
      )
    end

    def end_date
      Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(<<-SQL
         CASE WHEN DATE_PART('hour', NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'ICT') < #{Time.now} THEN (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day') ELSE CURRENT_DATE END
      SQL
      )
    end
```

When I try to test by `generate_series.to_sql`. I meet exception:

> Arel::Visitors::UnsupportedVisitError: Unsupported argument type:
>   String. Construct an Arel node instead.

I try to shorter my code for testing:

```
def generate_series
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('GENERATE_SERIES', ['19/11/2012', '20/11/2012', '1 day'])
 end
```

The problem is same. Please tell me how can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your last parameter should be an `Arel::Nodes`. So you should wrap `1 day` into an `Arel::Nodes:SqlLiteral`. Here is updated code:

```
def generate_series
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('GENERATE_SERIES', 
             [start_date, end_date, Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('\'1 day\'')]
      )
end
```

Noted that you must also wrap `1 day` inside (single) quotes, i.e: `'1 day'`. Because if you don't do this, the generated query will be:

```
GENERATE_SERIES(start, stop, 1 day)
```

But true query should be:

```
GENERATE_SERIES(start, stop, '1 day')
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Arel::Nodes.build_quoted` to quote literals:

```
def generate_series
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('GENERATE_SERIES', 
             [start_date, end_date, Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('1 day')]
      )
end
```

The advantage of this is that you don't have to remember to include and manually escape quotes like you do with `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral`.